# Centos 7 Installation problems

Tags: centos

I want to install `CentOS 7` in a virtual machine wih virtual box but when I choose the option `°Tes this media and install centos 7°` I get this error:

```
    Checking: 090.5%

The media check is completed, the result is: Fail

It is not recommended to use this media.
[Failed] Failed to start Media Check on /dev/sr0
See ´systemctl status checkisomd5@-dev-sr0.service´for details.
[ 191.018148 ] dracut-initqueue[540]: Job for checkisomod5@-dev-sr0.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status checkisomd5@-dev-sr0.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[ 191.552636 ] dracut : FATAL: CD Check failed!
[ 191.554295 ] dracut: Refusing to continue
[191.874800 ] System halted.
```

What I can do?
Have a good day
[image: Error]

Comment: That means something went wrong with either the download or _if you use it_ the burning process. Futhermore, we need a little more info, including the host OS, whether your using the ISO image directly or if your burning it to a CD/DVD media. the md5 tool your using, _if any_ . That way we know more on what could go wrong and how can we best assist you.

Comment: Well,I have a laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium, I´m using VirtualBox, I downloaded from the official website centos with utorrent.

Comment: I downloaded the minimal version and error no longer appears :3, probably the .iso file is corrupted...

Comment: yup, that seems to be the problem. I'm glad you were able to solve it,